# Creating and modifying a global statement in SAS

Tags: variables, sas, global

I would like to do something very simple, but it doesn't work
This is a simple example but I intend to use it for some more complex stuff
the output I want is :

```
obs. dummy newcount
1 3 1
2 5 2
3 2 3
```

but the output I get is :

```
obs. dummy newcount
1 3 1
2 5 1
3 2 1
```

here is my code

```
data test;
input dummy;
cards;
3
5
2
;
run;

%let count=1;

data test2;
set test;
newcount = &count.;
%let count = &count. + 1;
run;
```

The variable count doesn't get incremented. How do I do this?
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing macro variables and datastep variables in a way you cannot.  Macro variables used in the data step in most cases have to have their values already defined prior to the data step when used like this; what happens is the data step compiler immediately resolves &count to the number 1, and uses that number 1 in its compilation, not the macro variable's newer values.

Further, the %let is not a data step command but a macro statement - it is also only executed once, not one time per data step pass.

You could use

```
data test2;
set test;
newcount = symget("count");
call symput("count",newcount+1);
put _all_;
run;
```

and it would work (call symput is how you define a macro variable in a data step, symget is how you retrieve the value of a macro variable that isn't finalized before the data step begins).  It is probably not a good idea, however - you shouldn't generally store data values in macro variables and interact repeatedly with them inside a data step.  If you post more details about why you're trying to do this (ie, what your actual goal is) I'm sure several of us could offer some suggestions for how to approach the problem.

Comment: Thanks !
It doesn't work yet, I get few error messages... My questions are : where do you put the initial value for count? Why is your count why "" ?
The bigger problem is that I have a column full of -1, 0, and 1s.
Say : 1, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, 1, 0
I need to count how many occurences of each I have in a row
The output would be :
., ., 3, 1, ., 2, 1, 1 
(you put a . when it's not the last occurence)
Does that help?

Comment: actually nvm I fixed the errors. My bigger problem is still here, if you have any idea?
Also, newcount is interpreted as text instead of numbers by SAS. Any fix?

Comment: Your bigger problem is that you don't really understand SAS.  You should not use macro variables like what you are doing - Forget that macros are possible or exist at all, and write this in data step language entirely.